# how to solve [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth

I'm trying to enable the bluetooth when its off using react native by this code

when its turned on the modal asking permission using bluetooth is showed up, but i want to show modal alert again when the bluetooth turned off. So how to show the modal it can be redirect to settings on both android and ios ?

```
    this.setState({ isEnabledSwitch: !this.state.isEnabledSwitch })
    const bluetoothPermission = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.BLUETOOTH_PERIPHERAL : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_PERIPHERAL;
    request(bluetoothPermission).then((result) => {
      console.log('result', result);
      const title = '“Wynn Resorts” would like to use Bluetooth';
      const description = 'Wynn Resorts needs your Bluetooth enabled to use Digital Key features to access your room with your phone. Please go to Settings > Wynn Resorts and turn on Bluetooth in order to allow access.';

      Alert.alert(
        title,
        description,
        [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => {
              this.isDialogShown = false;
              // this.gotoWayfinding();
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Settings',
            onPress: () => {
              this.isDialogShown = false;
              if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
              } else {
                this.props.navigation.goBack();
                NativeModules.OpenSettings.openNetworkSettings(data => {/*This is intentional*/ });
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        { cancelable: true }
      );
    }).catch((error) => {/*This is intentional*/ })
  }
```

but when i try in real device the xcode show logs of

`2022-03-14 19:19:05.493649+0700 appsTrial[657:117152] [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid`

how to solve this problem?